# Primefaces: Select same row in p:dataTable multiple times

Tags: jsf-2, datatable, primefaces

I have a simple `p:dataTable` which fires an AJAX event when selecting a row:

```
<p:dataTable var="c" value="#{myBean.dmCars}"
             selection="#{myBean.car}" selectionMode="single">
  <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{myBean.select}"/>
  <p:column>  
    <f:facet name="header">Name</f:facet>  
      <h:outputText value="#{c.name}"/>  
  </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

This works fine, but I can only select a row once. I want to select the same row multiple times and the event listener of `p:ajax` invoked for each click.

**Update** I think it's because the row has somewhere the state *selected*. You see the selected row with a grey background in this example: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionInstant.jsf

Comment: just a wild guess... try adding rowKey="#{c.someUniqueID}" to your dataTable...

Comment: @Daniel: Thanks for this hint, but it does not solve the issue.

Comment: From your question it is not quite clear what you are trying to achieve. Select multiple times means select->unselect->select again?

Comment: @MattHandy: I want that each time I click on the row the `p:ajax` is fired. Perhaps I need a different event other than `event="rowSelect"`.

Comment: Did you try event="click"? In the Primefaces example this row is highlighted that displays the value of `selectedCar`.

Comment: @MattHandy: `<p:ajax> Event:click is not supported`

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=3832

Answer (score 0):

@Daniel and @MattHandy, thank you both for your support. I found a solution to this issue:

```
public void select()
{
  // Do some stuff
  car=null;
}
```

In the backing bean i set the value holder to `null` after I've processed the event.

Comment: are you sure that your list had no duplicate entries ?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. At least in the list from the example above. By clicking on a row in this table, a object is created with a @ManyToOne reference to the distinct elements of this table and shown in another table.